# Consolidating "dust transactions" in account-based coins like Ethereum?

Tags: ether, gas, gas-price, fees

Suppose I have a marketplace where 100 buyers deposit 1 ETH each into 100 unique addresses and I know I will end up sending all 100 ETH to 1 vendor. Since the coins are originating from 100 ETH addresses (accounts) I would incur an extremely high transaction fee (1 transaction fee per address * 100 addresses = 100 transaction fees).

Does it make sense to send all 100 ETH to "one address" (account) when gas fees are low or using longer confirmation times in order to reduce my gas costs? If not, what strategy can be used to reduce miner/transaction fees in this case?

Comment: "100 buyers deposit 1 ETH each into 100 unique addresses" - this by itself doesn't make any sense. Those 100 buyers already have their own 100 unique addresses, why would they send 1 ETH to another set of 100 unique addresses???

Comment: @goodvibration because they need to deposit ETH on the platform in order to be credited to be able to buy something on the platform.. Example: A user deposits 1 ETH on our platform and is now able to spend 1 ETH. When the item is marked as delivered the 1 ETH is transferred to vendor using an "internal ledger". Suppose 100 different users buy something from this vendor worth 0.01 ETH (approx. $100 USD at time of writing) and the vendor chooses to withdraw his earnings we send all the total amount (0.01 ETH * 100 =  1 ETH) to the vendor in one transaction..

Comment: Also, "an extremely high transaction fee" is a matter of perspective. Each user by itself only pays a fee for his/hers single transaction. The accumulated fee may be high, but no single account pays that amount. It's like saying apples are extremely expensive because every year, 1 billion apples are bought in the US for 1 billion dollars.

Comment: @goodvibration let's say the average deposit on the platform is $100 and the average withdrawal is $10,000. If the $10,000 originates from 100 deposits (100 users) then the transaction fee would be 100 times higher compared to if one user deposited $10,000 and purchased $10,000 worth of merchandise from one vendor. Am I wrong?

Comment: But you don't have 1 user, you have 100 users.

Comment: @goodvibration yup, we have 100 users making a deposit of 1 ETH each (when each ETH = $1,000). Vendor ABC is selling shoes for $100 and sells 100 pairs of shoes to each of our 100 users. When the vendor wants to withdraw all of his earnings (0.1 ETH * 100 = 10 ETH or $10,000 USD) the transaction fee would be 100 * gas costs, because the 10 ETH originated from 100 addresses. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why would the vendor have 100 different addresses to withdraw from and not just 1? Why would those 100 users send ETH to 100 different addresses? When 100 customers buy shoes from the same shoe store, does each one of them pay into a different cash register? Are there 100 different registers in the store, which the store owner collects the cash from?

Comment: @goodvibration because when the 100 users deposit crypto (to top up their account balance) we/they don't know which vendor they will buy from. They are topping up their account balance so they can purchase from any vendor they choose at the time of their choosing. So each user deposits ETH to the ETH address linked to their account (i.e, a dedicated address) so we can track who to credit when a deposit is made (imagine all 100 users sending to the same address it would be impossible to know who sent which funds and who to credit)

Comment: @S.O.S On ethereum you can use smart contract wallets with CREATE2 opcode to process each user payment. See this article to understand how they work https://blog.coinbase.com/usdc-payment-processing-in-coinbase-commerce-b1af1c82fb0.

Comment: Why do they each need to transfer from one address (their own account) to some other address (unique for each user) that you can track? You may as well just track their own addresses directly.

Comment: @goodvibration by "their own account" I mean from their wallet which is hosted outside of our platform. They are transferring from their own wallet to our wallet as the funds have to be held in escrow until the item is delivered. Buyer X purchases a pair of shoes from Seller Y for $100 or 0.1 ETH. The platform holds 0.1 ETH from Buyer X in escrow until the tracking shows the shoes were delivered to Buyer X or Buyer X manually confirms delivery of the shoes. If Buyer X never deposits ETH into an address we control - how can we hold/lock his funds in escrow?